# Displaying varying images from buttons in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, button

I'm writing a program where the user gets 3 different buttons to choose from and according to which button they choose, a different image (or gif in this case) will appear. I've split the program into 3 classes: a GUI Window class, a GUI class, and a Color Panel class. The problem is I can't get the images to load when the buttons are clicked.

```
/******************************GUIWindow*******************************/
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIWindow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GUI theGUI = new GUI();
        theGUI.setTitle("Merry Christmas!");
        theGUI.setSize(500, 600);
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        theGUI.setVisible(true);
    }
}

/******************************GUI*******************************/
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private ImageIcon cat1 = new ImageIcon("cat1.gif");
    private ImageIcon cat2 = new ImageIcon("cat2.gif");
    private JButton cat1Button = new JButton("1");
    private JButton cat2Button = new JButton("2");
    private JButton cat3Button = new JButton("3");

    public GUI()
    {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(cat1Button);
        buttonPanel.add(cat2Button);
        buttonPanel.add(cat3Button);

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        cat1Button.addActionListener(new cat1Listener());
        cat2Button.addActionListener(new cat2Listener());
    }

    private class cat1Listener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(Color.white, cat1);
            Container pane = getContentPane();
            pane.add(panel);
        }
    }

    private class cat2Listener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(Color.white, cat2);
            Container pane = getContentPane();
            pane.add(panel);
        }
    }
}

/******************************ColorPanel*******************************/
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private ImageIcon image;

       public ColorPanel(Color backColor, ImageIcon i)
       {
          setBackground(backColor);
          image = i;
        }

       public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
       {
          super.paintComponent(g);

          int x = (getWidth() - image.getIconWidth()) / 2;
          int y = (getHeight() - image.getIconHeight()) / 2;

          image.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
       }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to display the ImageIcons in a JLabel and simply swap Icons using the JLabel's `setIcon(...)` method.

Comment: Swing tag added, eclipse tag removed as the question has everything to do with Swing and nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for the help! The program works now! :D Also thanks for helping me with my tags, sorry it's my first time using this website.

Comment: You are welcome to summarize your solution into a self-answer.